# Shopware 6 dynamic topseller products

Tags: shopware

In Shopware 6 there is the field `markAsTopseller` in the product entity. I can't find any reference to where this field gets set, so is this a field that is supposed to be set manually?
Ideally there would be a scheduled task or another process that would calculate the topseller-products in any intervals and set the field on the appropriate products.

Answer (score 2):

It is to be set manually by the "Product production" switch in the product editor (Admin path: `/admin#/sw/product/detail/$UUID/base`).

[image: product promotion screenshot]

I am not aware of an automatic task. This probably needs programming or there might be a plugin on https://store.shopware.com/ (I did not find one in a quick search though).

Be aware, that depending on the nature of your product catalog it might be problematic to show those products which are sold most as topsellers. For example you might sell small products, cheap products the most (like screws, if it is a technical shop), but might want to promote more interesting / expensive articles as topsellers (like coffee machines).

If you want to make an automatic job check [out the documentation on scheduled tasks](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/tutorials-and-faq/creating-scheduled-tasks).

Comment: Thanks for confirming my thoughts!
You're obviously right with your argumentation about topseller products just being based on sales. But that's as you said highly dependent on the catalog :)